# I set the outlined style for edit text but it did not set correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, material-design

I set the outline style for edit text but it did not set correctly.

xml code (edit texts):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="عنوان"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDescription"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="متن یادداشت"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTitle" />
```

images of app:

[image]

[image]

what's the problem?

Comment: Post the code, not the image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the outline style on the `AppCompatEditText`, you need a `TextInputLayout` and setting it there.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="عنوان"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

First one is using a `TextInputLayout`, second is what you have now.

[image]

[Material Design reference](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#outlined-text-field)

Answer (score 0):

make sure your activity theme is Material Theme. if you are not using Material Theme this won`t be working.

just like, check the activity theme,

[image]

go to theme. your theme must be inherited from,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```